# What causes "Error C stack overflow" in haskell usually

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation

What are the usual causes of "Error C stack overflow" in the Hugs Haskell implementation.

Comment: Which implementation?  HUGS?  NHC?  GHC?

Comment: All the answers seem to be talking about overflowing the Haskell runtime's stack.  The C stack is different, at least in GHC.  Is this a confusing error message, or is the problem actually FFI-related.  (I have done a lot of FFI work and have never seen this.  But I use GHC.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can come up if you are used to functional languages in which it is common to do tail-recursion factorization.  Say you have a function:

```
sum = go 0
    where
    go accum [] = accum
    go accum (x:xs) = go (accum+x) xs
```

Which, incidentally, is the same as

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

If we evaluate the function we can see the problem:

```
sum [1,2,3,4]
go 0 [1,2,3,4]
go (0+1) [2,3,4]
go ((0+1)+2) [3,4]
go (((0+1)+2)+3) [4]
go ((((0+1)+2)+3)+4) []
(((0+1)+2)+3)+4
```

Now to evaluate that expression Haskell uses a stack:

```
EXPR            | STACK
(((0+1)+2)+3)+4 | 
((0+1)+2)+3     | +4
(0+1)+2         | +3 +4
(0+1)           | +2 +3 +4
1               | +2 +3 +4
3               | +3 +4
6               | +4
10              |
```

And *this* is where an overflow can occur.  If you evaluated sum [1..10^6], that stack would be a million entries deep.

But note the pathology here.  You recurse over a list only to build up a huge fscking expression ("thunk"), and then use a stack to evaluate it.  We would rather evaluate it as we are recursing, by making the tail recursion strict:

```
sum = go 0
    where
    go accum [] = accum
    go accum (x:xs) = accum `seq` go (accum+x) xs
```

That says to evaluate accum before trying to evaluate the recursive call, so we get (this may take a some patience to understand):

```
sum [1,2,3,4]
go 0 [1,2,3,4]
let accum = 0 in accum `seq` go (accum+1) [2,3,4]
go (0+1) [2,3,4]
let accum = 0+1 in accum `seq` go (accum+2) [3,4]
go (1+2) [3,4]
let accum = 1+2 in accum `seq` go (accum+3) [4]
go (3+3) [4]
let accum = 3+3 in accum `seq` go (accum+4) []
go (6+4) []
6+4
10
```

So as we are traversing the list, we are computing the sum so we don't have to use a deep stack to evaluate the result.  This modified tail recursion pattern is encapsulated in Data.List.foldl', so:

```
sum = foldl' (+) 0
```

A good rule of thumb is to *never use foldl*, because it always builds up giant thunks.  Use foldl' instead.  If the output type has lazy structure (eg. a list or a function), use foldr.  But there is no silver bullet for avoiding a stack overflow in general, you just have to understand the evaluation behavior of your program.  This can be hard sometimes.

But, if I understand correctly, a stack overflow *always* comes from trying to evaluate a gigantic thunk, though.  So look for places where those could be created, and force evaluation to happen earlier.

Answer (score 1):

A runaway recursion is the most likely candidate... You need to give more info though for a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that could cause a runaway recursion:

```
main =
  let x = x :: Int
  in print x
```

What happens here is that when `x` is evaluated in `print x` it starts, then finds out that to complete its evaluation it needs to evaluate `x`.

Comment: That probably won't cause a stack overflow though, because of TCO (note that x is a tail call in x).  This would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Hmmm...  So it is, luqui.  I was sure that kind of code generated stack faults last time I tried it (admittedly a few years ago).

Comment: Oops.  I was right, but different situation.  If I run that code in GHCi it just loops forever.  If I compile it and run it I get the error:  a.out: <<loop>>

Comment: ttmrichter, that's *not* stack overflow. GHC's RTS detects that you're evaluating the same thunk and "solves" the halting problem magically :)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause has to be uncontrolled recursion. Each recursive call consumes a little more stack space for its input/ouput parameters.

Comment: Only if you define "recursion" correctly.  Haskell has a pretty different idea of what consumes stack space than most functional languages.