# Do stack overflow errors occur in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow

As a pure functional programming language, Haskell intensively uses recursion. Do stack overflow errors occur in Haskell, like in Java? Why, or why not?

Comment: Haskell compilers like GHC perform tail call elimination https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call. Tail-recursive functions don't cause stack overflow in well-implemented functional languages.

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert May I ask how it is implemented?

Comment: Tail call elimination is transformation of recursive calls into loops, or `goto`s, basically, to evade pushing new stack frames.

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert GHC does not perform tail call elimination for tail-recursive function calls.  It wouldn't really make sense, because function calls are not evaluated on a call stack.

Comment: @JustinL. [Yes it does.](https://donsbot.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/write-haskell-as-fast-as-c-exploiting-strictness-laziness-and-recursion/)

Comment: Lazy functional languages don't need tail call elimination to avoid stack overflows. If you implement a straightforward graph reduction engine where everything's on the heap, the equivalent of tail call (not just recursion) elimination falls out of laziness for free, anyway; I'm not surprised that GHC transforms tail recursion into assembler loops for efficiency, but it doesn't need to for stack management. The kind of stack overflow you can get in Haskell (too many nested thunks, not too much recursion depth) can actually be introduced by trying to transform your code to tail recursive form!

Comment: In Haskell, using tail recursion can be be beneficial or detrimental depending on the context. E.g. summing a list using tail recursion and a (strict!) accumulating argument is good. Implementing `foldr` with tail recursion is horrible, even when disregarding infinite lists.

Comment: In Java and some other languages, I think the runtime puts a relatively arbitrary bound on the stack because in such language it is unidiomatic to recurse too much, so exceeding -say- 10000 call frames is unconventional, hence forbidden, even if the OS memory would allow much larger stacks. (JVM has a flag to change the limit, however) Because of this, I guess many programmers "learn" that recursion is inherently bad and should be avoided at all costs in imperative code. And this reinforces recursion being unidiomatic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Haskell uses the stack differently from Java, due to laziness.

In Java, a stack frame is created when a method is called, and freed when the method returns. So if `f()` is a recursive method, each recursive call to `f()` generates a stack frame, and these frames are strictly nested. You can get a stack overflow when you have a deep chain of recursive calls, like `f() -> f() -> f() -> …`.

Whereas in Haskell, a *thunk* is created when a function is called. A stack frame is created when a thunk is forced using pattern-matching (e.g. `case`), and freed when evaluation of the thunk is complete enough to return a value (which may contain more unevaluated thunks).

So if `f` is a recursive function, each call to `f` generates a thunk, and `case` on the result of this generates a stack frame, but these frames are *only* nested when there’s a dependency between thunks. And in fact, that’s what the `seq` primitive does: `` a `seq` b `` means “evaluate `a` before `b`, returning `b`”, but you can also think of it as adding a dependency of `b` on `a`, so when `b` is evaluated, `a` is also forced.

You can get a stack overflow when you have a deep chain of *thunks* to evaluate, for example in the excessively lazy `foldl` function:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..5]
==
foldl (+) 0 (1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : [])
==
((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5
```

This generates a chain of thunks like so:

```
((+)
    ((+)
        ((+)
            ((+)
                ((+)
                    0
                    1)
                2)
            3)
        4)
    5)
```

When we force the result (for example, by printing it) we need to descend all the way down this chain in order to be able to *start* evaluating it, at the `(+) 0 1` thunk.

So `foldl` often produces stack overflows for large inputs, which is why most of the time you should use `foldl'` (which is strict) when you want a left-associative fold. Instead of building a chain of nested thunks, `foldl'` evaluates the intermediate results immediately (`0+1 = 1`, `1+2 = 3`, `3+3 = 6`, …).

Comment: Note that the problem with `foldl (+)` is the fault of both `+` and `foldl`; because `+` is fully strict, the outermost `+` think can't do anything without forcing the thunk in one of its arguments, and so on along the whole chain. But if the operation you gave to `foldl` was instead building a data structure with more structure than an integer, it might return a constructor without forcing the entire chain. You'd still get as many thunks as list cells since `foldl` doesn't generate the outermost one to return until it's consumed the entire list, but they wouldn't have to blow the stack.

Comment: @Ben I'd expand on your comment with 1) I'd describe `+` in terms of how _productive_ it is, rather than in terms of strictness (though maybe they are one and the same here), 2) `+` _can_ be productive if we're dealing with peano numbers, say :-) 3)  also worth pointing out that in that case (where you're passing a productive function, rather than `+` on `Int`s) `foldr` is still better (if it's possible to use) since you then avoid the one-thunk-per-cell you mention

Comment: @jberryman Good points. If your function is not associative though then the choice between `foldr` and `foldl` is one of semantics, not just efficiency. Generally I'd prefer to choose based on that first, and only jump through hoops trying to fit `foldr` where `foldl`is more natural if it turns out I need to, rather than have "`foldr` is better " as a blanket rule. Most of the time it's an unnecessary micro optimisation (occasionally very necessary to get something that runs acceptably at all).

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflows won't occur in Haskell like they would in Java, etc., because evaluation and function calls happen differently.

In Java and C and other similar languages, function calls are implemented using a call stack.  When you call a function, all of the function's local variables are allocated onto a call stack, and when the function finishes, the function is popped back off of the stack.  Too many nested calls, and the call stack will overflow.

In Haskell, that's not necessarily how function calls work.  In most compilers, like GHC, Haskell function calls are *not* implemented using call stacks.  They are implemented using a completely different process, using allocation of thunks on the heap.

So, most haskell implementations don't implement a call stack for function calls in the first place, so the idea of a stack overflow is non-sensical.  It'd be like talking about bath tubs overflowing in a locker room with only showers.

(GHC does use a call stack for thunk evaluations, but not for function calls.  So stack overflows that might happen are of a completely different and unrelated nature than stack overflows from Java, C, etc.)

Comment: ghc does use a call stack, but for thunk evaluation rather than for function calls.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462780/what-causes-error-c-stack-overflow-in-haskell-usually)

Comment: @luqui thanks; i see where that might cause confusion.  edited my answer to clarify this.