# haskell optimise code and stack overflow in tail recursion

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell, recursion

As I am trying to learn functional programming I have decided to do the advent of code challenges in haskell.

While doing challenge 5 https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/5
with input data https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/5/input I have encountered several problem.

This is my code

```
import Data.Array
import System.IO

listToArray l =
  let n_elem = length l
      pos_val = zip (range (0, n_elem)) l
  in array (0, n_elem-1) pos_val

getData filename = do
  s <- readFile filename
  let l = map read (lines s) ::[Int]
      a = listToArray l 
  return a

-- Part 1

updatePosArray i a =
  let i_val = a ! i
  in (i+i_val, a//[(i, i_val + 1)])

solution1 a n_steps i
 | i >= length a || i < 0 = n_steps
 | otherwise =
    let ai = updatePosArray i a
    in solution1 (snd ai) (n_steps+1) (fst ai)

-- Part 2

updatePosArray2 i a =
  let i_val = a ! i
  in
    if i_val>=3 then (i+i_val, a//[(i, i_val-1)])
    else (i+i_val, a//[(i, i_val+1)])

solution2 a n_steps i
 | i >= length a || i < 0 = n_steps
 | otherwise =
    let ai = updatePosArray2 i a
    in solution2 (snd ai) (n_steps+1) (fst ai)


main = do
  x <- getData "/Users/lucapuggini/Documents/AdventOfCode/data/data_ch5_p1.txt"
  let x_ex = array (0,4) [(0, 0), (1, 3), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, -3)]

  let n_steps_ex1 = solution1 x_ex 0 0
  print $ n_steps_ex1

  let n_steps1 = solution1 x 0 0
  print $ n_steps1

  let n_steps_ex2 = solution2 x_ex 0 0
  print $ n_steps_ex2

  -- very slow. Probably due to the immutable array
  let n_steps2 = solution2 x 0 0
  print $ n_steps2
```

and this is the result I get :

```
lucas-MacBook-Pro:src lucapuggini$ stack runhaskell challenge5.hs

    5
    381680
    10
    stack overflow
```

the code is quiet slow but this is probably expected due to the fact that I am using immutable array but I am surprised by the stack overflow error. I thought that this should not happen with tail recursion.

In conclusion I have 2 questions:

1) Why am I getting stackoverflow error? Am I using tail recursion wrongly?

2) What is a more efficient but still functional way to run this code? Are immutable array a bad choice?

I am very new to haskell so please be clear.

Comment: The "stack" in Haskell is not a function call stack; that's why tail recursion isn't relevant.

Comment: what is the right way to run that code?

Comment: this works
```lucas-MacBook-Pro:src lucapuggini$ stack ghc challenge5.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( challenge5.hs, challenge5.o )
Linking challenge5 ...
lucas-MacBook-Pro:src lucapuggini$ ./challenge5
5
381680
10
29717847
```

Comment: What Haskell implementation are you using, and what version? I didn't think GHC *had* stack overflow errors anymore.

Comment: Also, yes, if you're writing code like this, it doesn't really make sense to use immutable arrays. Switch to mutable arrays, or use something with faster pure operations like `Data.IntMap.Strict`.

Answer (score 3):

*With respect to your first question (why the stack overflow):*

Using `stack runhaskell` (or equivalently `stack runghc`) runs your code in a special "just in time" compilation mode, much the same way expressions entered at the GHCi prompt are run.  The code is unoptimized and will frequently exhibit terrible performance characteristics.

For your particular program, this means it runs very slowly, with an ever-expanding memory footprint, and eventually produces a stack overflow.

If you instead compile and run with:

```
stack ghc -- -O2 challenge5.hs
./challenge5
```

you'll find that it runs much faster (about a minute on my laptop), in constant memory, and, obviously, without a stack overflow.

As indicated in the comments, a stack overflow error in GHC doesn't really have anything to do with tail recursion.  Instead, it arises from a particular aspect of lazy evaluation.  (See [Do stack overflow errors occur in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265198/do-stack-overflow-errors-occur-in-haskell), for example.)

Briefly, GHC creates "thunks" representing unevaluated expressions whose value can be demanded at a future point.  Sometimes, these thunks get linked together in a long chain in such a way that when the value of the thunk at one end of the chain is needed, all the thunks down the chain need to be "partially evaluated" to the end of the chain to get the last thunk's value before the program can start calculating thunk values all the way back up the chain.  GHC maintains all these "thunk evaluations in process" in a stack with finite size, and that can overflow.

A simple example to trigger a stack overflow is:

```
-- Sum.hs
main = print $ sum [1..100000000]
```

If you run this with:

```
stack runhaskell -- Sum.hs      # using GHC version 8.0.2
```

you'll get:

```
Sum.hs: stack overflow
```

However, compiling it with `ghc -O2` is enough to make the problem go away (both for `Sum.hs` and in your original program).  One of the reasons is likely the application of a "strictness analysis" optimization that forces thunks early so these long chains can't form.

*With respect to your second question (is an immutable array the right approach):*

As @WillNess points out, using unboxed arrays in place of boxed arrays gives a huge performance improvement:  on my laptop, an unboxed version of your code runs in 8 secs versus 63 secs.

However, with this type of algorithm -- basically, where a large number of small changes are made incrementally to a vector in such a way that the changes to be made depend on the whole history of accumulated previous changes -- you can do much better with a *mutable* array.  I have a version using `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` that runs part 2 in 0.12 secs, and you should be able to achieve similar performance with a mutable unboxed array from `Data.Array.Unboxed`.

Comment: Mutable array seems to be the most reasonable choice. But I thought that mutable structure should be avoided in functional programming

Comment: Those who subscribe to this view would actually say that mutable structures should be avoided in *all* programming.  It's just easier in functional languages.  The argument (which I won't make here!) is that immutable algorithms lead to cleaner design and fewer bugs, and the potential inefficiencies of copying data to make small changes can usually be optimized away by careful data structure design and clever compilers.  However, some algorithms are still more easily implemented using mutable data structures, so we settle with using them "sparingly".

Comment: the problem is with the implementation, whereas for the unboxed immutable array `a`, `a // [(i,e)]` [in tail position](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array) should be *O(1)*, but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you import `Data.Array.Unboxed` instead of `Data.Array`, and declare your array as

```
    ....
        a :: UArray Int Int 
        a = listToArray l
    return a
```

or something, in `getData`, you'll get significant speedup, bordering on miraculous.

Also, you will have to re-implement `lengthArr = rangeSize . bounds`, so it works for the unboxed arrays.