# Haskell - Recursion Stack Overflow

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to sum all n from 1 to a very large number (10**9 for now) but it gives stack overflow. Also I don't think putting a stop at 1 and doing the sum n in different rows is the most efficient way but the code below is all my knowledge for Haskell. I really don't know much about functional programming and I would like as much explanation as possible. (Also I have tried putting $! strict in the last line which was told in other places but it changed nothing. I would be glad if you explained the most efficient way I could do this recursive function.)

```
main :: IO()

summ 1 = 1
summ n = 1/(n**2) + summ (n-1)

expected_value = pi*pi/6
errorPercent n = n / expected_value * 100

main = do
    putStr "%"
    print (errorPercent (summ $! (10**9)))
```

Comment: Oh by the way you can write `summ` as `summ n = sum [ 1 / i^2 | i <- [1..n] ]`. Nice, right?  (Make sure to compile with optimizations for this one)

Comment: @luqui - I think you'd want `sum [ 1 / i^2 | i <- reverse [1..n] ]` to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: @Omnifarious interesting!  I had never thought about issues like this.  I can't quite see why it happens though...

Comment: @luqui - Happens due to rounding. Floating point numbers work best when the numbers being added together are similar in magnitude. Otherwise, the bits being added from the small number sort of rotate off the end of the large number and don't even change it. So, even if you add several hundred thousand tiny numbers like that they don't change the original number at all.

Comment: @luqui - Unfortunately, Haskell's reverse requires actually evaluating the whole list to be reversed. So you have to come up with some kind of reverse countdown list to make it work without taking gigabytes of memory. Luckily, that's not too hard.

Comment: @Omnifarious, oh that makes sense.  So for maximum accuracy adding a large list of numbers, we should sort it by increasing magnitude (if it's a left fold).  ... Right?  That makes intuitive sense, but I can't rule out that there might be some choice of association e.g. ((x1+x4)+(x2+x5))+x3 which would achieve even better accuracy.

Comment: @luqui - As a rule of thumb, yes. I can also imagine that in some specific cases different orderings may be better. There are other rules for other operations as well. I don't know what they all are, but I do know that making the most of floating point precision is something to be thought through carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that  sums can not start being computed until the whole 10^9 recursion calls are over. Essentially, you are computing

```
1/(n**2) + ( 1/((n-1)**2) + ( 1/((n-2)**2) + ....
```

and the parentheses prevent to start summing. Instead, we would like to have

```
(( 1/(n**2) + 1/((n-1)**2) ) + 1/((n-2)**2) ) + ....
```

The easiest way is to use an "accumulator" additional argument:

```
summ 1 acc = 1 + acc
summ n acc = summ (n-1) $! acc + 1/(n**2)

main = do
    putStr "%"
    print (errorPercent (summ (10^9) 0))  -- set acc to 0 at the beginning
```

For improving the performance, I'd recommend to add a type signature to `summ` e.g. `summ :: Int -> Double -> Double`.

---

Full program below. This runs in 12s here (`ghc -O2`).

```
summ :: Int -> Double -> Double
summ 1 acc = 1 + acc
summ n acc = summ (n-1) $! acc + 1 / (fromIntegral n**2)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "%"
    print (summ (10^9) 0)  -- set acc to 0 at the beginning
```

Comment: It has worked and I could get output from 10^9 but it is really slow. I am currently waiting for 10^10 and 10^9 took like 20 minutes. Is this speed normal or is there ways to make it faster?

Comment: @Terobero Are you running the code after compilation with optimization e.g. `-O2`? If you are running it using GHCi instead, that is usually quite slow.

Comment: Im using VSCode & Stack. How do I do the thing you said in Windows?

Comment: @Terobero I have no idea about VSCode. I guess it does compile code with GHC, since it runs `main` instead of giving you a REPL prompt (right?). There should be some place in its options where you can add `-O2` if that's not already on. From the command line instead I would use `stack ghc -- File.hs -O2`

Comment: @Terobero See the last edit. Without `errorPercent`, and with `-O2` on, the program with 10^9 here runs in 12s. Your 20 minutes is way too much.

Comment: @Terobero the direct compilation with ghc at the Windows Command prompt is as simple as running `C:> ghc -O2 name.hs` in the directory in which the file `name.hs` resides.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. I have one last question. You used type Int and fromIntegral. Is there a reason you did that and not used a Double type?

Comment: @Terobero For integer variables, it's faster and safer to use `Int` or some other integral type. Using `Double` can cause subtle issues since e.g. `x == x+1` when `x` is a large enough `Double`, and rounding errors can easily break the program. I'd tend to avoid floating point except when an inexact approximate value is good enough (e.g. not when we need precise comparisons such as `if x == 1 then ...`). luqui in his answer shows why using `Double` does not work here.

Answer (score 10):

chi has answered one bit of the question, which I think is the main problem, but there is something else that is bugging me.  When you say `10**9`, you get a *floating point* number (because `**` is "fractional" exponentiation).  And then you are using floating point equality to check for the base case of your recursion.

```
summ 1 = ...
```

The problem with this is that it is possible, and as the argument gets larger, likely, that because of numerical error you will just barely miss the base case and descend into negative values forever.

```
summ 4 =        ... summ 3
summ 3 =        ... summ 2.000001
summ 2.000001 = ... summ 1.000001 
summ 1.000001 = ... summ 0.000001  -- BASE CASE MISSED!
summ 0.000001 = ... summ (-1.000001)
summ (-1.000001) = ... summ (-2.000001)
```

and so on.  If you didn't get a stack overflow from 10<sup>9</sup> calls, you surely will with infinitely many.

You should either define your function on integers so there is no rounding error

```
summ :: Int -> Double
summ 1 = 1
summ n = 1 / (fromIntegral n ** 2) + summ (n - 1)
--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- conversion necessary to go from Int to Double

main = ... print (summ (10 ^ 9))
--                      ^^^^^^
--      use integral exponentiation (^) instead of (**)
```

or use a more forgiving base case

```
summ :: Double -> Double
summ n | n <= 1 = 1
summ n = 1 / (n ** 2) + summ (n - 1)
```

In either case, you should definitely take chi's suggestion to do this in accumulator style, and you should also definitely put a type signature.

Here's [more on how you get stack overflows in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463078/33796) if you are curious.